# Getting data out of Quicken in a text format

Tags: quicken

How can I get my financial data out of Quicken in a text format.  I want to have a way to keep and access my data even if Quicken stops working.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a text format"?  Quicken will export a QIF file, which is a text format.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to print your account register to a text file.  Quicken won't help you here, but you can trick it to print to a .prn file.

Install the Microsoft generic text printer driver (instructions for Windows 10):

Click the start button
Open the "Settings" app
Open the "Devices" app
Click on "Add a printer or scanner".  Wait a bit
Click on "The printer that I want isn't listed"
Select "Add a local printer or network printer with manual settings"
Click "Next"
Select "Use an existing port" (default)
Select "FILE: (print to File)", like this:

[Port selection dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM2N6.jpg)

Click "Next"
Under "Manufacturer" select "Generic"
Under "Printers" select "Generic / Text Only"

This will install your generic printer driver.

Now, in Quicken go to File--Print [your account name]

Click through this process and select your new text printer, like this:

[Printer selection dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC8GV.jpg)

Select "Fit to one page wide"
Click "Print"
Enter your file specification.

The resulting .prn file can be opened with a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Quicken registers can't easily be exported as CSV files (which is probably what you meant by a text file -- comma-separated values), but Quicken *reports* can, and you can create a report that has the registry's full history. See the documentation, or websearch "export Quicken", for specifics.

Comment: Right on both points.  I just wanted to put this interesting method out for someone to find.  I wish Quicken would export and import registers to/from .csv,  It seems an obvious feature, but I guess it's a business decision.  One thing I was trying to get, that motivated me to try the printing trick, was the Posting Date.  Alas, that does not come out either way.